# SAS: Conditional sum by category

Tags: sas

Anyone have a good solution to the below? I need to sum down observations and take the value of 'dist' when the cumulative sum of 'total' reaches 1000;

```
data DATA  ;
input ID $ dist total ;
cards ;
A  1.5  600
A  2.5  500
A  3.0  200
B  2.8  1050
B  6.8  100
C  0.8  900
C  1.2  150
C  3.5  300

; run;



Desired output with the third column being optional:
A 2.5 1100
B 2.8 1050
C 1.2 1050
```

Comment: Can you include anything you've tried so far? [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By-processing with retained cumulative total and output flag :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by ID ; /* assumes your data is sorted already by ID */
  retain cumtot _out . ;
  if first.ID then call missing(cumtot,_out) ;

  cumtot + total ;

  if cumtot >= 1000 and not _out then do ;
    _out = 1 ; /*   set flag so we don't output further records for this ID */
    output ;
  end ;

  drop _: ;
run ;
```

I'd also refrain from naming a dataset "data".

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `if cumtot >= 1000 and _out ne 1 then do;` otherwise it will keep outputting?

Comment: Works great. thanks! Thanks also for the addition Reeza.